# how to detect a duplicate element between two json object in php

Tags: php, json

i trying to detect a different element between 2 json objects like this;

```
//Json1    
    [
        {"file":"arrowssss.png"},
        {"file":"arrows.png"},
        {"file":"logo.png"}
    ]
//Json1    
    [
        {"file":"arrows.png"},
        {"file":"logo.png"}
    ]
```

I need return Arrowsss.png.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Did you try, anything?

Comment: `array_diff(json_decode($Json1, true), json_decode($Json2, true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}

$json1 = '[{"file":"arrowssss.png"},
        {"file":"arrows.png"},
        {"file":"logo.png"}]';

$json2 = '[{"file":"arrows.png"},
        {"file":"logo.png"}]';

$array1 = flatten(json_decode($json1,true));

$array2 = flatten(json_decode($json2,true));

print_r(array_diff($array1,$array2));
```

Results :-

```
Array ( [0] => arrowssss.png )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json1='[
    {"file":"arrowssss.png"},
    {"file":"arrows.png"},
    {"file":"logo.png"}
]';
$json2 = '[
    {"file":"arrows.png"},
    {"file":"logo.png"}
]';
function getFile($key)
{
    return isset($key['file']) ? $key['file'] : null;
}
$diff = array_diff(array_map('getFile', json_decode($json1, true)), array_map('getFile', json_decode($json2, true)));
print_r($diff);
```

Result:-

```
Array ( [0] => arrowssss.png )
```